# Why does tracing not work in ASP.NET MVC child actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, calls to HttpContext.Trace.Write and System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write from a parent Controller method (or from a business object it invokes) lead to entries in Trace.axd.

If a child action is invoked by the parent view e.g. Html.RenderAction("ChildAction") then trace statements within the ChildAction Controller method are not reflected in Trace.axd.
Yet if I hit http://localhost/Home/ChildAction directly then the statements do appear in the trace.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some website configuration required to allow tracing to work for child actions and any business methods they invoke?

*HomeController.cs:*

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HttpContext.Trace.Write("blah");
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("blah diag");
    var b = new Business();
    b.DoStuff();
    return View();
}

public ActionResult ChildAction()
{
    HttpContext.Trace.Write("child action trace");
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("child action diag");
    var b = new Business();
    b.DoStuff();
    return Content("some content");
}
```

*Index.cshtml:*

`<h2>Index</h2>`
`@{ Html.RenderAction("ChildAction"); }`

*web.config:*

`<trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" mostRecent="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="1000" traceMode="SortByTime" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="false" />`

`<system.diagnostics>

  <trace>

    <listeners>

      <add name="WebPageTraceListener"
           type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>

    </listeners>

  </trace>

</system.diagnostics>`

Answer (score 0):

DGreen, perhaps you could try using Glimpse ([website](http://getGlimpse.com)). It has it's own TraceListener implementation that might solve this problem for you.